# Does GRUB2 support multi-line textual descriptions?

Tags: grub2

In SYSLINUX, one can provide a multi-line description for a menu entry like so:

```
LABEL foo
MENU LABEL Foobar the system
TEXT HELP
  This is a long-form description about how you really shouldn't do this
  unless you're really, really sure.
ENDTEXT
```

Is any equivalent to this functionality (displaying such a description when a specific item is selected) available in GRUB2?